# codeigniter pagination Numbers not displayed correcly

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

Codeigniter pagination Numbers not displayed correcly in result page,.

Plz help me.

/*controller page code*/

```
  function search_all()
  {
    $this->load->view(‘prd’); 
  $config = array();
  $config[‘base_url’] =  base_url().’/product_search/search_all’;
  $config[“total_rows”] = $this->search_product_model->record_count();
    $config[“per_page”] = 8;
    $config[“uri_segment”] = 3;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data[“results”] = $this->search_product_model->
    get_search($config[“per_page”], $page);
    $data[“links”] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    //$this->load->view(“example1”, $data);
  $this->load->view(‘asd’, $data);
  }
```

Comment: Please display your controller and your view that deal with the problem at hand. We can't help you based off your current explanation.

Comment: You must post some code. We can't see in your head!

Comment: /*model page code*/
  
      function get_search($limit, $start)
      {
      $match3 = $this->input->post(‘search3’);
      $this->db->like(‘color’,$match3);
      $match2 = $this->input->post(‘search2’);
      $this->db->like(‘type’,$match2);
      $query = $this->db->limit($limit, $start)->get(‘products’);
      return $query->result();
      }
      
      public function record_count() {
          return $this->db->count_all(“products”);
        }

Comment: /*view page code*/
  
      foreach($results as $data) {?>
      <?php echo $data->id ?>
      <?php echo $data->code ?>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
  
  <?php echo $links; ?>

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an problem with this

```
  $config[“total_rows”] = $this->search_product_model->record_count();
```

For this you are not passing the search keys such that it will count all the data which it contains.If you get the record count based on search key then it will be fine.Like this

```
  $config[“total_rows”] = $this->search_product_model->record_count('//search parameters');
```

and in your model:

```
Public function record_count($search_params)
{
   $this->db->where('product',$search_params);
   return $this->db->count_all(“products”);
}
```

You can modify as your needs like pass "color","type" to your record_count() function and based on that,you suggested to get "count_all".I hope it will works for you

Comment: $config["total_rows"] = $this->search_product_model->record_count('');

Comment: function record_count($search_params)
{
   $this->db->where('products',$search_params);
   return $this->db->count_all("products");
}

Comment: In my search displayed product 1 record..but pagination numbers displayed (1,2,3).. i put condition Perpage displayed 8 records..how controll page numbers?

Comment: That means you want to display (1,2,3,4...)like that...??or (1,2)

Comment: i want search record displayed above 8 record, need paging (1,2)like that..otherwise below 8 record displayed in search result page,pagination number not need display..

Comment: $config[“total_rows”] = $this->search_product_model->record_count() = 2; right..???

Comment: yes right. (example) choose color:red, product display 2 record..but pagination number displayed(1,2)..that's error..

Comment: If there is an error in url..??send me the entire url and try base_url(product_search/search_all) and tell.??

Comment: $config['base_url'] =  base_url().'/product_search/search_all'; i removed that line..but's working fine..I'm working on local host...search result product displayed correctly,but i need to avoid pagination number in just 2 product displayed on result page,,that's my point

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 function search_all()
 {               
   $config[‘base_url’] =  base_url(’product_search/search_all’);
   $config[“total_rows”] = $this->search_product_model->record_count();//2 in your case
   $config[“per_page”] = 8;
   $config[“uri_segment”] = 3;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
$data[“results”] = $this->search_product_model->
get_search($config[“per_page”], $page);
$data[“links”] = $this->pagination->create_links();

//$this->load->view(“example1”, $data);
$this->load->view(‘asd’, $data);
}
```

and at your model:

```
 public function get_search($limit, $page)
{
 //Add this...???
  $this->db->limit($limit, $page);  //or try $this->db->limit($page,$limit)

}
```

Comment: public function get_search($config[“per_page”], $page)            Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

Comment: Missing argument 1 for search_product_model::record_count()

Comment: Undefined variable: search_params

Comment: @murai...you are not supposed to copy all the things i given.just make some simple edits as per your need "EVEN".

Answer (score 0):

give search key in the record_count() function as parameters //You got 2 na.??

Then in placeof search_params put you same keys which are supplied to the record_count()